# WooCommerce - Hide product images if none

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, woocommerce

I'm developing a theme in Bootstrap which uses WooCommerce. I'm trying to hide the col-md-1 which the product images/gallery are in, if there is none, and make my product image column from col-md-5 to col-md-6

**The page design consists of 3 columns:**

1. col-md-5 - Product image
2. col-md-1 - Product images/gallery
3. col-md-6 - Product information

[Here you can see where the product has more images in the col-md-1](http://mimac.weshape.dk/produkt/brun-hardcase/)

[Here you see it without product images](http://mimac.weshape.dk/produkt/brun-hardcase-2/)

Comment: How are you displaying the gallery in the first place? Hard to tell you how to modify your code without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code which will help you.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
if(jQuery('.col-md-1').children().length===0){
jQuery('.col-md-1').css('display','none');
jQuery('.col-md-5').toggleClass('col-md-6');
jQuery('.col-md-5').removeClass('col-md-5');
}
});
```

Load the page in a browser first then paste the following code in console to see the effect.

If this code is what you want then add the same to conditionally load it on a single product pages only.

Comment: Why do in the front end something needs to be done in the backend? plus there is no js tag in the question

Comment: As it has twitter-bootstrap tagged in the question have given the solution in jQuery.